# $this acting alone in the php code

Tags: php

I have been confused by `$this`.I know `$this->somevaribale` used for refering global values...But i have seen a code like

```
class ClassName
{

private $array; //set up a variable to store our array

/* 
 * You can set your own array or use the default one
 * it will set the $this->array variable to whatever array is given in the construct
 * How the array works like a database; array('column_name' => 'column_data')
 */
function __construct($array = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'vegetable' => 'cucumber')) {
    $this->array = $array;
}

/*
 * Loops through the array and sets new variables within the class
 * it returns $this so that you may chain the method.
 */
public function execute() {

    foreach($this->array AS $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value; //we create a variable within the class
    }

    return $this; //we return $this so that we can chain our method....
}

}
```

Here `$this` is called alone ...Am really confused with this..When i remove $this and replaced with $this->array i get error..

So my question is what is the use of calling `$this` alone and what it represents.

Thanx for the help.

Comment: $this is referring to the object containing `$array`.

Comment: see Fluent Interfaces

Comment: @Wold object containing $array means ??..supose if i call like $wold = new classname() ..so $this refers to $wold ??

Comment: @honeysingh No. you can only return '$this` and reference '$this` within the context of the class or function. if you are declaring `$wold = new classname();`. `$this` is not now associated with `$wold`, only in the class.

Comment: so $this ===  $wold inside the class ??

Answer (score 0):

$This is a reference for PHP Objects. You can learn more about objects and how $this works in the PHP manual [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

A class is a kind of "blueprint" of an object, and vice versa, and object is an instance of a class. When `$this` is used within the class, it refers to itself.

```
$hi = new ClassName();
$hi->execute()->method()->chaining()->is_like_this();
```

`$hi` refers to a `ClassName` object, and the function `execute()` returns the object itself.

```
$ha = $hi->execute();
// $ha refers to a ClassName object.
```

Method chaining (fluent interfaces) enables one to tidy up the code if one normally calls many methods of that object:

```
$hi->doSome();
$hi->doAnotherThing();
$hi->thirdMethodCall();
$hi->etcetera();
```

will become

```
$hi->doSome()
    ->doAnotherThing()
    ->thirdMethodCall()
    ->etcetera();
```

Comment: so $this inside the class refers to the object of the class ?/ ie $hi ?

Comment: Indeed, `$this` refers to the object on which the method is called.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of corrections to the terms you use:

- `$this` is a reference to the "current" object, not "global values"
- you're not "calling" anything here; *functions* are *called*, you're just using `$this` (which, again, is a variable holding an object)

So, `return $this` returns the current object as return value of the method. This is usually just done to facilitate fluent interfaces, a style where you can write code like:

```
$foo->bar()->baz()
```

Because `bar()` returns an object (the `$this` object), you can call its method `baz()` right afterwards.

Comment: so here $foo->bar() === $this inside the class ??

Comment: Inside of `bar()`, `$this` === `$foo`.

Comment: so here when i run like $name = new classname(), $name->execute() .so $name->execute === $foo right ??

Comment: What? No! Inside of the `execute()` method, `$this` refers to `$name`. And if you `return $this`, then `$name->execute()` returns `$name` essentially.

Comment: so inside the execute() method $this === $name(object of class) right ?

Comment: Right. `$this` refers to the *current* object instance of the class, the particular instance whose method was called.